# how to forward http request in node js

Tags: node.js, http, pipe

I want to take the a request, forward it to another url and return the result of the forwared request.

This is my code:

```
const http = require('http'),
      server = http.createServer().listen(3000);

const baseUrl = 'foo.bar';

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
    req.headers.host = baseUrl;

    var connector = http.request(req, (resp) => {
        resp.pipe(res);
    });

    req.pipe(connector);
});
```

Sadly, I'm getting an error, that the socket hung up.

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:203:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:288:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:903:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
```

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Try to configure new request object manually, and do not change `req` object.

This works:

```
const http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer().listen(3000);

const baseUrl = 'www.i.ua';

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  var connector = http.request({
    host: baseUrl,
    path:'/',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: req.headers
  }, (resp) => {
    resp.pipe(res);
  });

  req.pipe(connector);
});
```

So, you should have something like this:

```
const http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer().listen(3000);

const baseUrl = 'radio.i.ua';

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  var connector = http.request({
    host: baseUrl,
    path: req.url,
    method: req.method,
    headers: req.headers
  }, (resp) => {
    resp.pipe(res);
  });

  req.pipe(connector);
});
```

Comment: Have been trying to get this to work with no success for authentication headers :(

Comment: Just add `headers` section to http.request. `http.request({headers: req.headers})`